# Point free composition of two functions when second takes return val of first AND ALSO the parameters of the first function

Tags: typescript, functional-programming, composition, pointfree, fp-ts

Say I'm writing a function that will make an HTTP call to fetch data. I've broken down the API call into smaller functions that I compose:

```js
const buildPayload = (inputs:Inputs) => reader.of({...inputs, some:'bar'}) // (inputs:Inputs) => Reader<unknown, Payload>
const buildUrl = reader.of('path/to/call') // Reader<unknown, string> (will be Reader<BaseUrl, string>)
const options = reader.of({options:{headers: /*...*/ }}) //Reader<unknown, AxiosOptions>

// (inputs:Inputs) => reader<unknown, [string,AxiosOptions,Payload]>
const fetchDeps = flow(buildPayload, _ => sequenceT(reader)(buildUrl, options, _))

// (inputs:Inputs) => reader<unknown, ()=>AxiosResponse<any>>
const fetchThunk = flow(fetchDeps, reader.chain(deps => ()=>axios.post(...deps)))

// And so forth
export const apiCall = flow(fetchThunk, /*...*/) // (inputs:Inputs) => ReaderTaskEither<TokenAndBaseUrl, DomainError, RequestedApiData>
```

Using `flow` I've managed to minimize how often I define the input parameters. It's just one place, in `buildPayload`, and I don't have any implicit `any` arguments). This makes it easy to change parameters if new requirements show up: update one place and the change cascades through the rest of the code. I think this is called "point-free programming."

This is easy when every step is dependent on the previous step but nothing else. But let's say the first step in the flow is `const foo = (a:A)=>B` and the second step is `const bar = (a:A,b:B)=>C` so that the first step is dependent on the result of the first step *but also* expects parameters that are the same as the first step.

How can I do this and still be point-free (assuming I'm using that term correctly)?

`flow(foo, bar)` does not work because then `bar` needs to accept the return value of `foo` as its parameters.

I can just define them as `foo = (a:A) => ...` and `bar = (a:A, b:B) => ...` and then

```js
export const apiCall = (inputs:A) => pipe(foo(inputs), _ => bar(inputs, _), /*...*/)
```

But now I've had to define `(inputs:A)` in three places: definition for `foo`, `bar`, and `apiCall`. If I change the params, I have to update three different function parameter lists.

Comment: This form of composition is supplied by the Applicative instance of the function type, here in curried form: `const funAp = tf => tg => x => tf(x) (tg(x))`. As you can see the `x` argument is passed to both arguments of the binary function. This way you achieve the effect of a shared argument that is implicitly threaded throughout your composition. Here is a [more thorough explamantion](https://github.com/kongware/scriptum/blob/master/course/ch-016.md#function-instance).

Comment: In FP-TS this is probably called the `Reader` monad. Please note that for the function type Applicative and Monad instances are equivalent, because `flip` witnesses an isomorphism between them.

Comment: @bob I understood most of what you wrote, and it got me to think about using Reader, so I did. I treated `foo = (a:A) => B` as `Reader<A,B>` and curried `bar= (a:A, b:B)=>C` to get `bar = (a:A) => (b:B) => C` and then made it `Reader<A, (B)=>C>` and then used `sequenceT` to give me `Reader<A, [B, (B)=>C]>` and from there I could feed B into (B)=>C by using `Reader.map(([a,b]) => b(a))`. Is that what you were talking about? Or is there something about `ap` that I'm missing? I 100% have trouble understanding `ap` or what it's useful for, so if you meant `ap` it's no surprise I missed your point!

Comment: and why I did this with Reader, sequenceT (which converts multiple monads into a single monad wrapping an array of the monad effectful results), and map rather than ap. I think the definition of the fn is `sequenceT = (m:M<A>) => (...args:M<A>[]) => M<A[]>`

Comment: If this is indeed what you meant, feel free to put this as an actual answer and I'll mark it correct!

Comment: The Reader type just offers a composition similar to the one you described in your title, that's all I tried to point out. For the `Reader` type `chain` (monad) and `ap` (applicative) are just equivalent, because you can transform one into the other using `flip`. You can read more about this in my [JS course](https://github.com/kongware/scriptum/blob/master/course/ch-016.md). Unfortunately, I cannot help you with FP-TS.